# How to find out whether a file has been commited with CRLF?

Tags: git, gitattributes

The git documentation [states](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#Documentation/gitattributes.txt-Settostringvalueauto):

> When the file has been committed with CRLF, no conversion is done.

How do I (does git) find out whether a file has been commited with CRLF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git ls-files --eol <path/to/file>
```

will output that info. ([doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files#Documentation/git-ls-files.txt---eol))

Hint :
`i/` means "index" and
`w/` means "working tree"

Comment: works great, but sometimes it gives unexpected results: `i/crlf  w/crlf  attr/text=auto  myfile` but the hash gets calculated using `lf` line endings (`git hash-object myfile`outside repository only gives same hash as inside repository if the line endings have been converted to `lf`.)

Comment: Interesting remark, thanks for the feedback. I'll have to research this a bit.

Comment: I'm not sure `--eol` tells you the right thing here. At most, it inspects the index copy, which might differ from the committed copy. The source prints `i/%s` based on: `if (ce && S_ISREG(ce->ce_mode)) i_txt = get_cached_convert_stats_ascii(...)`

Comment: This call reads the blob data using the index hash, then calls `gather_convert_stats_ascii` on that. The code is a bit tricky here. The blob data read is from slot 2 if we're in a merge, or from slot 0. It does look like it reads the entire contents into memory for analysis, regardless of how big the file is.

Comment: Meanwhile `get_cached_convert_stats_ascii` returns a string based on bits set in `gather_convert_stats`. This returns 0 ("none") if the size is 0. Otherwise it calls `gather_stats` to count lone \r, lone \n, \r\n, "printable" and "nonprintable", and \0 bytes; calls `convert_is_binary` to turn on the BIN flag; sets TXT_CRLF if there are \r\n sequences; and sets TEXT_LF if there are lone \n.

Comment: Curiously, `convert_is_binary` returns 1 (true) if there are any lone \r (??).  If not, it returns true if there are any NULs (this counts most utf-16 files as binary, which is probably wrong). If not, it returns true if there are not at least 128 "printable" characters for every "non-printable" character.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this code (modern Git, 2.25) is quite different from a few years ago, when it was a lot more "inspect the first 8k"-ish. :-)